# Como Fazer um scraping com Python para comparar preços em um site de compras?

Tags: python, web-scraping, comparação

Comparando o preço de um mesmo produto a cada minuto e me notificando quando o valor cair 50%. Usei um While >= mas está retornando um erro indicando que não pode usar >= entre str e int.
Ele acaba retornando o preço como uma string.

Vou mostrar o código como está:

https://github.com/ViniciusCavalcante2000/Scraping-de-pre-os/blob/main/scraping%20de%20pre%C3%A7os%20Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--hedless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.magazineluiza.com.br/ssd-480gb-kingston-sata-rev-3-0-leituras-500mb-s-e-gravacoes-450mb-s-a400/p/220920100/in/ssdi/')
sleep(3)
produto = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/h1').text
preçoatual = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
preçoalvo = 300

while preçoatual >= preçoalvo:
    print(preçoatual)
    sleep(1)
print('preço alvo atingido')



____________________________________________________________________________






Código alterado após as sugestões do amigo:

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--hedless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.magazineluiza.com.br/ssd-480gb-kingston-sata-rev-3-0-leituras-500mb-s-e-gravacoes-450mb-s-a400/p/220920100/in/ssdi/')
sleep(3)
produto = driver.find_element_by_class_name('header-product__title').text
preçoatual = driver.find_element_by_class_name('price-template__text').text
preçoatual = preçoatual.replace(',', '.')
preçoatual = float(preçoatual)
preçoalvo = 300

print(produto)
while preçoatual > preçoalvo:
    print(preçoatual)
    driver.get('https://www.magazineluiza.com.br/ssd-480gb-kingston-sata-rev-3-0-leituras-500mb-s-e-gravacoes-450mb-s-a400/p/220920100/in/ssdi/')
    sleep(3)
    produto = driver.find_element_by_class_name('header-product__title').text
    preçoatual = driver.find_element_by_class_name('price-template__text').text
    preçoatual = preçoatual.replace(',', '.')
    preçoatual = float(preçoatual)
    sleep(5)
print('preço alvo atingido')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o problema é apenas o valor estar como `string`, basta converte-lo para `float`.

```
preçoatual = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[2]').text

# Para isso será necessário remover os caractere "." que estiverem na variável e
# depois pegar os caracteres "," e substituir por ".", assim será possível fazer a
# conversão sem gerar erros.
preçoatual = preçoatual.replace('.', '')
preçoatual = preçoatual.replace(',', '.')
preçoatual = float(preçoatual)
```

No entanto pelo que verifiquei no link do site, você está pegando o título do produto ao invés do valor. Então para facilitar e dar mais certeza que você está pegando o elemento correto, recomendo você pegar o valor pela classe dele. Para isso basta utilizar a função `find_element_by_class_name()` do `selenium`. A classe do elemento que possui o preço do produto é `price-template__text`.

[image]

então basta substituir:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
```

Por:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('price-template__text').text
```

link para a função `locate_element_by_class_name()`:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name

Agora outro detalhe importante para te informar, é que a forma que você esta comparando, acredito que esteja incorreta. Você está armazenando uma única vez o preço do produto e logo depois você usa ele para comparação no bloco `while`. Sendo assim você está comparado o mesmo preço do produto toda a vez. Para contornar isso, sugiro que você troque o operador do `while` e depois insira uma função para atualizar os dados da página e fazer a consulta do preço dentro do `while`, assim o valor na variável será sempre atualizado.

Comment: Mano, segui suas sugestões e realmente funcionou tudo! Testei o bloco while e tá comparando certo com o preço alvo. Quando eu troco o preço alvo, inserindo o valor atual, ele sai do laço while e printa "preço alvo atingido". Deixa eu aproveitar e perguntar. Qual seria a melhor maneira de eu receber uma notificação? Por email, Whatsapp, se for possivel. Também, é muito complicado deixar esse código em um servidor? Vou mostrar o código já alterado editando minha pergunta. Você salvou o dia. Obrigado.

Comment: Você está certo quanto ao laço while e o preço que estou comparando. Ele está em loop na mesma informação.